# Raspberry pi GPIO.add_event_detect crash

Tags: raspberry-pi3

i have just recently started to play around with raspberry pi and 
cannot understand what is happening using GPIO.add_event_detect feature.

The basic program detects when GPIO16 drops due to button press, prints a message, sleeps 1 second and then prints another message. i switch off and on event_detect during callback to avoid switch bounce causing additional callbacks. The issue is however after only two button presses the program crashes??
This happens every time i run the program. GPIO.VERSION '0.6.2'

Here is the program:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def pressButton(channel):
        GPIO.remove_event_detect(channel)
        print("Button Pressed")
        sleep(1)
        print("Button Released")
        GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.FALLING, callback=pressButton, bouncetime=5)

GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.FALLING, callback=pressButton, bouncetime=5)

try:
    while True:
        sleep(1)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

And here is the output showing crash after 2 button presses:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Button Pressed
Button Released
Button Pressed
Button Released

>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>>
```

any help appreciated !